# Toggle Button won't update Value in while loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface, while-loop, togglebutton

I wrote a code that can constantly read the value of a matrix sensor (Matrix Sensor 1610), create a matrix and save it in an editor file.

I’m trying to implement my code into a GUI (Matlab) which I’ve never done before and I already ran into a problem.

All I got is a toggle_button to turns the process on and off.
For me to have a matrix I’m using a while loop. In that loop I need to ask for the value of the toggle_button. The state of the button stays at “1” as long as I’m in the loop, regardless of what I do.
I can only change the state of the button when I'm out of the while loop

I guess there’s something fundamental that I don’t understand. Can somebody 
please help me?

Thank you so much in advance

I did read similar problems but it didn’t work with my code.

Here is my code for the button

```
    % --- Executes on button press in OnOff.
    function OnOff_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    % setup serial

    global onOff_Button
    onOff_Button = get(hObject, 'Value')

    %Preparation

    delete(instrfindall)        %Reset Com Port
    delete(timerfindall)        %Delete Timers

    % setup serial
    serialPort = serial('COM3');
    command = 'A';

    nrow = 16;
    ncol = 10;
    row_index = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
    col_index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    % 10x16 = 160 bytes
    lendata = 160;

    BaudRate = 115200;

    InputBufferSize = 500;

    Timeout = 1;

    set(serialPort , 'BaudRate', BaudRate);
    set(serialPort , 'InputBufferSize', InputBufferSize);
    set(serialPort , 'Timeout', Timeout);

    fopen(serialPort);

    if onOff_Button == 1

    %Saving Data
    fid = fopen('Test.txt', 'wt');

    while onOff_Button == 1

    % Request data
    fprintf(serialPort, command);

    % Get data
    %Data is read as string (CSV)
    data_string = fgetl(serialPort);
    data_string_array = strsplit(data_string, ',');
    data = str2double(data_string_array);

    % Reshape data (1D -> 2D array)
    data2d = zeros(nrow, ncol);
    k = 1;
    for i = 1:nrow
       for j = 1:ncol
          data2d(row_index(i), col_index(j)) = data(k);
          k = k + 1;
       end
    end

    % Open for writing
    for i=1:size(data2d,1)
       fprintf(fid, '%g\t', data2d(i,:));
       fprintf(fid,'\n');
    end
    fprintf(fid, '\n\n');

    %clean out the InputBufferSize
    flushinput(serialPort)

% Asking the Value of the Button   
 onOff_Button = get(hObject, 'Value')

    end

fclose(fid);
    fclose(serialPort);

    else

    end

    %end of every funktion
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your problem with a minimal example: Just having a while loop in the toggle button-callback function, which reads the state of the button every second and stops when the value is 0. Anyway, it worked. So can you please post a small, not working example, which we can test in MATLAB (without the file and serial port stuff)?

Comment: Try adding `pause(0.1)` somewhere in the loop.

Comment: Thank you guys. @bushmills it always works with small examples. It never seemed to work when I had it work some lines, then a while loop.

Comment: Until @ThP... Thanks works fine with the pause. Do you know why? Thank you both

Comment: Yes. Matlab updates the GUI state only when idle. What you did is busy waiting. That means that matlab has no chance to do that.